# Error occurs when trying to start Java GUI in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

1. [GameLauncher class](https://pastebin.com/vUH86xtU)

```
package me.beanbeanjuice;

import me.beanbeanjuice.utilities.Game;
import me.beanbeanjuice.utilities.filehandlers.DictionaryHandler;
import me.beanbeanjuice.utilities.filehandlers.DistributionHandler;

public class GameLauncher {

    public GameLauncher() {
        new Window();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DictionaryHandler();
        new DistributionHandler();
        new Game();

        // TESTING. MenuScreen() should start first. MenuScreen() when "startButton" is hit, it should start game.
        //new Window();
        new GameLauncher();
    }

}
```

2. [Window class](https://pastebin.com/rDANfzjM)

```
package me.beanbeanjuice;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window() {
        super();
        setTitle("Boggle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new GamePanel(720, 1280));
        add(getContentPane());
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

3. [GamePanel class](https://pastebin.com/JjxMAW6u)

```
package me.beanbeanjuice;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    public GamePanel(int width, int height) {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setFocusable(true); // Allows the JPanel to have input as soon as the JFrame is made.
        requestFocus();
    }

}
```

4. [Error Message](https://gyazo.com/4a8b233217d35d288165c60557bb196c)
5. [Error Message in GameLauncher class](https://gyazo.com/e167c4de4f0dd797ecea255232409b83)

Hello, I'm following a tutorial for making a Java GUI in IntelliJ, and it won't even start. If you look at the last link, it shows this weird "error" and it won't start the GUI. It leads to the "Error Message" link as shown for link number 4. How do I fix this? I followed the tutorial exactly and even tried making a new project to no avail. I've tried swapping the Window() and GameLauncher() calls in the GameLauncher class but it is still not working. I've also tried with and without the super() call.

Comment: I don't see anything related to `JavaFX`, yet you are using the `JavaFX` tag.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with a display driver, however, I do not know if it still occurs. What fixed it was unplugging all of my external monitors, running the code, plugging them back in, stopping the code, running the code, then it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

In Window Constructor in the Window class, at this line `add(getContentPane());` you are adding container's parent to itself. This line is the same as writing `getContentPane.add(getContentPane())`.

I dont know what do you mean to put in the frame. Using JFrame you need to add the child to the JFrame's content pane. Removing this line works for me.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html